# Windows Service in Python

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, service

I am following the solution provided in the following link to create a Windows Service with Python that do not hang in STOPPING state when I try to stop it after some days running.

[Timeout and Windows Services for Long Running Processes (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482089/timeout-and-windows-services-for-long-running-processes-python/45359317#45359317)

The problem I am facing is that after I start the service it seems to run just once and the service in the windows service manager have all the tasks disabled so I can not stop or restart it. Below is my code. I have removed all the real tasks I want to perform and replace it by a dummy service that add 1 to a variable (x) every-time it runs and write it to a log file.

I would appreciate any tip in trying to find I where is my mistake.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 27 09:07:29 2017

@author:aaaa
"""

import threading
import logging
import logging.config
import win32api
import win32serviceutil
import win32event


class InterruptedException(Exception):
    pass

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self._controller = controller
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()

        self.x=0

        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Creating logger
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        logging.config.fileConfig(r'c:\temp\teste_logging.conf')
        # create logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('teste')
        self.logger.debug("Serviço criado")

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def run(self):
        try:
           # Insert the code you want to run as a service here
           # rather than do "execfile(.../.../blah)" simply do:
           # You can have your code throw InterruptedException if your code needs to exit
           # Also check often if self.stopped and then cleanly exit
           self.x+=1
           self.logger.debug('x = {}'.format(self.x))

        except InterruptedException as e:
           # We are forcefully quitting 
           self.logger.debug('Interruption Exception - {}'.format(str(e)))
           pass
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.debug('Unexpected Error - {}'.format(str(e)))
            pass
           # Oh oh, did not anticipate this, better report to Windows or log it
        finally:
           # Close/release any connections, handles, files etc.
           # OK, we can stop now
           win32event.SetEvent(self._controller)

class test_service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

   _svc_name_ = "pyTEST"
   _svc_display_name_ = "TEST Event service"
   _svc_description_ = "Service to teste python service"

   def __init__(self, args):
       win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
       self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)     
       self.hWaitDone = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

       #logger
       self.logger=logging.getLogger('teste.SERVICE')

       #create worker 
       self.worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone)

   def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager      
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 

        #worker = WorkerThread(self.hWaitDone,self.dCONFIG)
        self.worker.start()

        while True:
            # Wait for service stop signal
            rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([self.hWaitStop, self.hWaitDone],win32event.INFINITE,60000)

            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened as part of Windows Service Management
            if rc == 0:
                # Stop signal encountered
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(self._svc_name_ + " - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
                break

            if rc == 1:
                # Wait until worker has fully finished
                self.worker.join()

                # Determine from worker state if we need to start again (because run finished)
                # Or do whatever
                if not self.worker.need_to_start_again():
                    break

                self.worker.start()

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True

if __name__ == '__main__':   
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(test_service)
```

Here is the configuration of the logging module. just save it in a text file and save it as teste_logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root,teste

[handlers]
keys=logfile,consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter,logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_teste]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile
qualname=teste
propagate=0

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
args=(r'C:\temp\pyteste.log','a',5000000,20)
formatter=logfileformatter
```

Comment: The 2nd parameter of `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a boolean that determines whether it should wait for all objects. You're mistakenly passing `INFINITE` (-1) for this argument, which is a true value, so the wait always returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` (258) unless by chance both events are set.

Comment: But this also happen if I use rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 10000)

Comment: You're providing a timeout I assume to do something else in the loop and then wait again. If you don't want a timeout, use `win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([self.hWaitStop, self.hWaitDone], False, win32event.INFINITE)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason why the services task were disabled. I forgot to implement the SvcStop function.

```
def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
```

Nevertheless it still runing just once.

Comment: I have realized that the problem is that the rc(win32event.WaitForMultipleObject) is returning the value 258. Does anyone knows what this mean?

Comment: `net helpmsg 258` : The wait operation timed out.

Comment: ... and I see eryksun already explained why that is happening.